# Cant see Cython output in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, cython

I can't see Cython output in jenkins console.

I've attempted to flush the output with:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I also tried to use:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

***Here's the part of my code where I invoke Cython:***

```
# cythonize the files
setup(
    name=directory_name,
    ext_modules=cythonize(extension_list, build_dir="build",
                          compiler_directives=dict(always_allow_keywords=True, language_level=3)),
    cmdclass={'build_ext': Cython.Build.build_ext},
    packages=[directory_name])
```

directory_name is the target directory.

extension_list is the list of all target python files in the directory.

I'm recursively iterating my project directory, searching for all python files to cythonize.

***Jenkins command:***

```
python cython_setup.py --target_directory = "path/to/directory"
```

This line will show up in jenkins console but Cython output will not:

```
print('hello!')
```

Can anybody assist me with this issue?

***Entire script code:***

```
"""
create_cython_setup.py script

This script will iterate recursively all files and folders in a target directory.
For any file with a .py extension the script will add the file to a setup.py file used for Cython.
This script will ignore __init__.py files and other files,
listed in a cython_ignore.txt file if found in the directory.

"""

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import Cython
import argparse
import os, sys, io
import pathlib
import ntpath
import argparse

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
#unbuffered output from here on

def cythonize_directory(dir):
    """
    cythonize each .py file in the given target directory (ignore __init__.py)
    """

    # list all .py files in the operated directory
    py_files = list(pathlib.Path(dir).glob('*.py'))

    extension_list = list()

    for py_file in py_files:
        basename_file = ntpath.basename(py_file)
        file_name_no_extension = os.path.splitext(basename_file)[0]

        if not basename_file == "__init__.py":
            print(basename_file)
            extension_list.append(Extension(file_name_no_extension, [str(py_file)]))

    directory_name = ntpath.basename(dir)
    print('directory name = ', directory_name)

    # cythonize the files
    setup(
        name=directory_name,
        ext_modules=cythonize(extension_list, build_dir="build",
                              compiler_directives=dict(always_allow_keywords=True, language_level=3)),
        cmdclass={'build_ext': Cython.Build.build_ext},
        packages=[directory_name])



def cythonize_directory_recursive(dir):
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        # cythonize all sub directories as well
        if subdirs:
            for subdir in subdirs:
                if not subdir == "build" and not subdir == "__pycache__" and not subdir == ".cache":
                    path_to_subdir = os.path.join(root, subdir)
                    print(path_to_subdir)
                    cythonize_directory(path_to_subdir)

    # cythonize the directory
    cythonize_directory(dir)


def main(args):
    dir = args.target_directory
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'build_ext']
    # dir = os.getcwd()
    cythonize_directory_recursive(dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script Arguments')
        parser.add_argument('--target_directory', help='target directory to run the script')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        main(args)
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: How are you invoking setup.py on jenkins? This question doesn't have enough detail to answer. Please make a minimal example that triggers the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Hi, I'm invoking setup.py inlined from another script called cython_setup.py
I'll edit the question with more code and details